# Append child at node x?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I know that to remove a child node at a certain position in the DOM tree I can do this;

```
this.element.removeChild(this.element.childNodes[index]);
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to append child at node x like above but in reverse. In pseudo code it would be something like (I think);

```
this.element.appendChild(child at node[index]));
```

Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore):

```
this.element.insertBefore(element, this.element.childNodes[index]);
```

Comment: This will work great thanks! Was looking for about 15 minutes on mozilla dev and on here but couldn't find anything as I was searching for the wrong things!

Comment: @CarlG Pay attention that there is no `insertAfter` method supported.

Comment: I just tried searching for it and wondered why nothing was coming up! It is easily overcome though by adding or subtracting 1, thanks again.

Comment: @CarlG Or using `nextSibling` / `previousSibling`.